# Connecting to external database through telnet

Tags: java, unix, telnet, jtds

I have a java program that connects to a MS SQL database. The program works **perfectly** when running through eclipse however I get an error when I run it through AIX:

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.

I can successfully ping the server but am not able to telnet into the server.  I am also not able to telnet from my windows desktop.

I am using jtds to connect:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+dropez_ip_address+"/"+dropez_db_name;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try{

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dropez_db_username, dropez_db_password);

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Here is some documentation from jTDS regarding the issue, but I am still not able to resolve the issue.

```
Why do I get java.sql.SQLException: "Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect" when trying to get a connection?

The "Connection refused" exception is thrown by jTDS when it is unable to connect to the server. There may be a number of reasons why this could happen:

    - The server name is misspelled or the port number is incorrect.
    - SQL Server is not configured to use TCP/IP. Either enable TCP/IP from SQL Server's Network Utility app or have jTDS connect via named pipes (see the URL format for information on how to do this).
    - There is a firewall blocking port 1433 on the server.

To check whether TCP/IP is enabled and the port is not blocked you can use "telnet 1433". Until telnet doesn't connect, jTDS won't either. If you can't figure out why, ask your network administrator for help.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can successfully ping the server but am not able to telnet into the server. I am also not able to telnet from my windows desktop. " Do you mean that telnet is not installed, or you don't have permission to use it, or that you try to telnet there and nothing (or something) happens?

Comment: Telnet has nothing to do with this.  You are not connecting to the database via telnet.  Your database server is not allowing a connection on the SQL Server port (1433) from your app; this is likely a network configuration or firewall configuration problem and not a software problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL Server database probably doesn't have the TCP/IP protocol enabled, to enable it:

1. From the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> Configuration Tools, open the 'Microsoft SQL Server Configuration Manager'.
2. Expand ‘SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration’, and then click ‘Protocols for ’.
3. Right-click ‘TCP/IP’ and then click ‘Enable’. The icon for the protocol will change to show that the protocol is enabled.

For SQL Server 2008:

[image: SQL Server 2008 Network Configuration]

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008, when I open the SQL Server Configuration Manager, I find the database located under 'SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration - > Aliases'  the protocol is 'tcp' and I am not having any luck changing it.

Comment: @Mike I added a screenshot for checking it in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I dont have those options, possibly because the database is not mine but supplied by a hosting service?

Comment: @Mike If your db is in a hosting service and your desktop connects to the remote hosting service, it definitely has something to do with AIX firewall configuration, you need to enable 1433 port outbound traffic. Does the hosted service allow connections from any IP or they have to allow certain IPS? Check that too.

Comment: the hosting service said it was the firewall as well, ill look more into that, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you can't telnet on port 1433, you are blocked by a firewall somewhere in the middle between your machine and the server. That's not a java related problem.

May it be that when you say "it runs perfectly under eclipse but not AIX" you are taking about 2 different computers ? If so, the one with eclipse is not firewalled, the one where you deploy your app is blocked.

But again, nothing to do with java. It's a level 3 error (TCP layer) of TCP-IP model.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Yes, the program runs when I run it on my desktop, but not when I run it from the AIX server.

Comment: So, chances are you got a firewall on the AIX server blocking outgoing connection on telnet port, or a rule somewhere else on the network.